# Session Variable Attached to String

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript

I want to show the following string result only if the session variable `Session("PublicGID")` is set:

```
<% = strDB_DirectoryBannerImage %>
```

How would I go about it?

Comment: Tired and not thinking right is not an excuse to have SO do your thinking for you. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<%
If Session("PublicGID") <> "" Then
  Response.Write(strDB_DirectoryBannerImage)
End If
%>
```

Or, to be more compact:

```
<% If Session("PublicGID") <> "" Then Response.Write(strDB_DirectoryBannerImage) %>
```